# How to create a static route to access PC2( Attached Diagram) from PC 1

Tags: static-routes

[image: IMG:]

[image]

I'm trying to access a PC on the 2nd router connected to the same Modem. Routers in use are both ASUS, so the UI is the same.

Comment: The diagram is great, but I'm 100% sure this is a duplicate of a dozen other threads; it's probably the simplest kind of routing there is.

Comment: I have not found it to be that easy, and I have searched, but have not found the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Static routes have the same two mandatory fields, no matter what model or manufacturer it is.

If you're configuring router 1:

1. Destination – what are you trying to reach?

   You've already answered this one yourself: either the whole network B, or at least the single computer in it. Usually it's most useful to add a route for the whole network (**10.10.2.0 / 255.255.255.0**), but it is equally *possible* to route just a single host (10.10.2.35 / 255.255.255.255) or any other combination.
2. Gateway (next hop) – what's the next router in the path?

   In this case, the diagram makes it obvious that it's router 2. Since it has multiple IP addresses, you need to use the address that router 1 *already* knows how to reach (or in other words, address from a subnet that both routers are in). That's **192.168.1.20** in your situation.

Don't forget that router 2 needs the **opposite** static route as well (to subnet 1 via router 1), otherwise the PC would be unable to send you any responses to your packets.

Don't forget that router 2's *firewall* needs to allow the incoming packets.

Comment: OK, it is NOT that simple. If I was using a commercial router, I could do this in a minute, but on these Home routers, with all the firewalls and all, this is not looking to be that simple.

Comment: Router 1 ASUS RT-N12
Network/Host IP Mask  Gateway  Metric Interface

192.168.1.20 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.254 1 WAN



Router 2 ASUS RT-AC3200
Network/Host IP Mask  Gateway  Metric Interface
192.168.1.10 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.254 1 WAN



Modem
LAN IP ADDRESS/Gateway:
192.168.1.254 (I can ping the DG from both PC1 & PC2)

From PC 1(10.10.1.25)- DefaultGateway: 10.10.1.1
I cannot ping 192.168.1.20

From PC 2 (10.10.2.35) DefaultGateway: 10.10.2.1
I can ping 192.168.1.20
I can ping 192.168.1.10
But I cannot ping 10.10.1.25

Comment: How do I add a screenshot?

Comment: Use the 'Edit' link of your main post. (If it refuses to allow to embed the image, add it as a link.)

Comment: I did that, but I dont see the second image

Answer (score 0):

Router 1 ASUS RT-N12

Network/Host IP     Mask        Gateway         Metric      Interface
192.168.1.20        255.255.255.0   192.168.1.254       1       WAN

Router 2 ASUS RT-AC3200

Network/Host IP     Mask        Gateway         Metric      Interface  
192.168.1.10        255.255.255.0   192.168.1.254       1       WAN  
Modem LAN IP ADDRESS/Gateway: 192.168.1.254 (I can ping the DG from both PC1 & PC2)  
From PC 1(10.10.1.25)- DefaultGateway: 10.10.1.1  
I cannot ping 192.168.1.20   
From PC 2 (10.10.2.35) DefaultGateway: 10.10.2.1   
I can ping 192.168.1.20   
I can ping 192.168.1.10   
But I cannot ping 10.10.1.25   
[The Routes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9JJ0U.jpg)

What do I need to do?